# CSS Last Child Not Working for Nested Divs?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I was working on my personal site using Bootstrap and specifically on my resume section where I am creating a vertical timeline for my experiences.

For the last of my experiences for each section I want to make the line shorter to reflect the ending of the experiences for that section using the `:last-child` selector. However, I am having issues with it getting to work with nested divs.

For some reason, my CSS is only selecting the absolute last instance of `section-item` instead of the last `section-item` for each `section-col`.

Here is a snippet of my HTML:

```
<div class = "container h-100 contact-form">
  <h2>Resume</h2>          
  <div class = "row justify-content-center">
    <div class = "col-md-6">
      <div class = "section-col"></div>
      <h4>Education</h4>
      <br>
      <div class = "section-item">
         <h5>School Name Here</h5>
         <h6>Degree Here</h6>
         <p>Location | Class of</p>
      </div>
      <div class = "section-item">
         <h5>Second School Name</h5>
         <h6>2nd School Name Location</h6>
         <p>Graduation</p>
      </div>
      <br>
    </div>
    <div class = "section-col">
      <h4 class = "section-name">Professional Experience</h4>
      <br>
      <div class = "section-item">
        <h5>Company</h5>
        <h6>Position</h6>
        <p>June 2020 - August 2020</p>
      </div>
      <div class = "section-item">
        <h5>Other company</h5>
        <h6>Position</h6>
        <p>June 2020 - July 2020</p>
      </div><br>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Here is my CSS attempt: (The first block code is to generate the line and last is for the circle)

```
.section-item {
    border-left: 2px solid grey;
    padding-left: 15px;
    margin-left: 5px;
    height: 120px;
    
}

.section-item > h5{
    line-height: 80%;
}

.section-col .section-item:last-child {
    height: 70px; 
}

.section-item:before{
    content: " ";
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: #fff;
    border: 3px solid black;
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    left: 14px;
    right: 0;
   
}
```

Here's an image showing my issue:

[image: Here's an image showing my issue]

If anyone has any ideas on this, any input would be much appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Just use `.section-col:last-child .section-item:last-child` because CSS [:last-child](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:last-child) represents the last element among a group of sibling elements.

Comment: @skobaljic I tried that before but it unfortunately did not change anything.

Comment: Your first `.section-col` is not nested properly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `:last-child` inside each `.section-col` is a `<br>` element. So the selector `.section-col .section-item:last-child` doesn't match any element and has no effect.

You have three alternatives:

1. Use `:last-of-type` instead of `:last-child`
2. Ditch the `<br>` altogether
3. Wrap the `.section-item`s in a new `<div>` and address the `:last-child` there

Comment: Thank you! It was an issue with the selector targeting my <br>.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```
.section-col .section-item:last-of-type {
    background: #f2f2f2;
}
```